# s3fs & upload CSV directly to S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently trying to upload a CSV file directly on AWS S3. While the connection to AWS works, I still struggle to save the .CSV out of the **buffer**. How can I fix the last step?

```
    buff = io.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(buff, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(["a", "b", "c"])
    buff2 = io.BytesIO(buff.getvalue().encode())

    s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(
        anon=False,
        key=settings.ML_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secret=settings.ML_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    )

    BUCKET_NAME = 'fbprophet'
    with s3.open(BUCKET_NAME + "/test.csv", "w") as f:
        # What should I write in here?
```

Comment: f.write("") ? if you have already existing CSV you should use other ways to upload. This is only if you create your CSV on the fly.

Comment: Ah no it's not existing yet. I want to write it out of the buffer.

Comment: well if you don't know what available functions your varrabile has the easiest way is to print its properties. Try printing like this: print(f.__dict__) to see what methods f has. I think that the write method is there

Comment: It's probably easier just to write to a local disk file and then use the normal AWS SDK to upload the file to S3. Is there a particular reason you want to use `s3fs`?

Comment: I switched now to write the file in the "buffer" (?) and then upload it directly

Comment: I switched now to write the file in the "buffer" (?) and then upload it directly